# Transition fillColor with corona sdk graphics 2.0

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hey guys I'm looking for a way I can transition rect fill color with graphics 2.0 corona sdk. So basically start blue and then gradually change red over 5 seconds and then red to yellow etc...

Right now I'm using Atoko's color transition wrapper to transition between colors and was looking for an official way to do this with coronas own API.

Can this be done?

http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/color-transition-wrapper

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that fill color is not an attribute, it is set via a function call. So there is no official way. You could use `transition.to`, which Atoko's lib does. That lib just provides a convenience function that creates an object that has an "attribute" which, when set, calls the `setFillColor` on original object.

The other method is to use a timer, as done in http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/easy-setfillcolor-transition. The code is simpler to understand because there are no metatables overriding the `__newindex`, but the end result is same.

You should probably use whichever you are most comfortable with, unless you find that one of the two has a limitation that is not obvious on first inspection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll defo try out your method. Quick question though, is there any way I can loop Atoko's cTrans so that it goes straight to another function or another cTrans on complete?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one will help you:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/effects.html

Comment: Thamks for the help, I'll defo try out those effects